# Labview: save controls under a certain size

Tags: labview

I would like to log the values of all controls and indicators on a VI. I can do this by using the invoke node
ctrl val.get all
followed by saving the array of name/variant data clusters to disk using datalog vis.

However, I would now like to impose a size limit: I only want to save the data if the size is under a threshold (e.g. 100 kb) to avoid generating huge files (for instance if the front panel contains an image). I want this function to be generic, so I can't create a list of control names to exclude or sort by control data type.

It seems that one way would be to flatten the variant data to a string and then measure the size of the string, but this seems potentially problematic if the control contains an inordinately large amount of data (e.g. could end up creating a 1 GB string).

Is there a more refined way to handle this problem?

Comment: Are you loging on any particular events or time intervals? Can you share your block diagram?

Comment: If you've got controls or indicators containing problematic amounts of data then that's already going to be an issue at the point where you get the control value, surely, before even you think about flattening this to a string? You might be able to do something based on [this example](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Determining-the-Data-Type-of-all-Front-Panel-Controls-amp/ta-p/3510455) where you could check for images or arrays before trying to get the actual values. I would try asking this one on the NI and/or lavag.org forums for more help.

Comment: ...But to be honest, if you want to do this for an application you're designing then you should probably rethink your architecture so you don't have to - maybe use a functional global VI to store this data, for example. If you want it as a tool you can use on other people's VIs without rewriting them then maybe you're trying to invent something too general - perhaps it'd be easier just to get a list of controls/indicators of the particular target VI, then manually decide which of those you want to store, and configure your data-saving tool with that list?

Comment: The specific application is control of a microscope, but it's generically valuable for us to store the settings used to control equipment with the data generated by that equipment. That way we can determine the state of the system when a particular recording was made. Of course, we can (and do) store vital settings, but as changes get made to the software over time, what's vital can change, so it's really useful to just dump all the settings to disk, so we don't miss anything. We already save all the vi front panels as images but these are incomplete and hard to work with in other software.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to inspect each control type to then have a more efficient way to check the size of that type.  Your problem of flattening large strings can then be avoided for any known control types you detect.  Arrays, images, waveforms, etc could all be inspected once you know the type, specifically for their size without ever having to flatten the data.  This would allow you to save the small stuff, ignore known large stuff and still flatten any unknown or unhandled types to string to determine the size, then it stays generic and could be used for any VI.  The openG variant tools (among others) have lots of type inspection pieces to use on the controls so shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Good news (for you): LabVIEW is horrendously inefficient at rendering data onto the front panel (WRT memory).

Displaying data on a control takes something like 10x the memory it would take to flatten that same data to a string. There's not much by way of clever, lazy-loading for arrays or any of that. You can still do size filtering on the flattened string if you want to, but it's a safe bet that if the Front Panel is open, flattening control values (one at a time) to string is going to use a trivial amount of memory compared to the memory it takes just to put that stuff on the front panel.